# Hover glitch in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, safari, navigation

Our [website](https://omniumcargo.dk) is experiencing a hover glitch in the sub menus of the navigation when using Safari (13.0.5) browsers. The sub-menu stays visible after I also move out of the hover field. Clicking other elements hides the overlapped parts. Clicking search or switching back and forth between Safari and other programs seems to rerender the page and remove the glitch. The glitching elements are not selectable.
I tried styling it differently and enforcing the hide method via jquery but the glitch won't bug. Anyone an idea what to do?

[image]

Comment: Pls add a minimal code example.

Comment: @rx2347 I'm not sure which code snippet could provide useful information? I added a snapshot of the issue though. Also: the navigation seems to be rendered correctly in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: not much we can do here, if you don't, because nobody can actually test it or check for a fix. try coming up with a minimal example that demonstrates the bug. this is usually good to find errors anyways.

Comment: My thought is that users will visit the website [link](https://omniumcargo.dk/) and inspect the navigation and the Safari issue themselves, since the problem seems to be program/web-engine related.